# How to log when the finalize method was not called?

Tags: java, java-8

I am not using the finalize method in my application but this question is out of curiosity.

Assume that there is finalize method in a class and I would like to log a warning message that finalize was not called.

How to do this ?

Any tips ?

Comment: Can you share an example please

Comment: _was not called_? when do you think that _might_ happen? Or better, when it is called?

Comment: was not called or when it is called, in either case how do we log ?

Comment: That's a fundamental difference. You can easily log when it gets finalized, but considering that it has not finalized requires a point of time where you define that it should have been finalized until then, but no such time exist (except for the JVM exit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities--In either case, you need a singleton collection.

1) When each object is constructed add a unique key (String) that identifies the object--(but not the object itself!) to the collection.  When the finalizer is called, remove it's key from the collection.

At any given time, outstanding instances are available in the collection.

2) Okay, you CAN add the object itself to the collection if you really want to, but the collection must be a collection of the proper reference class.  This is harder and requires a little research--look into reference classes (WeakReference/PhantomReference/??).  I haven't looked at them for a few years and forget exactly which one does what, but this is exactly the kind of work the Reference classes were made for.

Be careful with 2, I think there is a chance that iterating through the reference collection could resurrect a dead class or stop one from being collected.

The reason for both caveats is that if you store a reference in a normal collection it will never be eligible for collection so no finalizer will ever be called.

Comment: The reference API is not very helpful here. A weak reference gets cleared when the objects is eligible to finalization, but it did not happen yet and there can be an arbitrary time until it happens, if it happens at all. On the other hand, a phantom reference requires the object to be finalized *and* detected as unreachable again, which might be much later. Further, you can only use it with a queue, which adds another delay. So to detect finalization, only a direct action in the finalizer, as with your first approach, will work as intended.

Comment: @Holger My thought was that identifying the ones that hadn't been collected is important.  A weak reference collection (WeakHashMap?) Can hold all the references and allow you access to the ones that hadn't been GCd without stopping any from being GCd if there are no other references.  I think that would be exactly what is wanted, but my assumption that Hari would want to review the objects that hadn't been collected yet (possibly to see why they hadn't been collected) could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM guarantees that the method will be called before the object is disposed, as per [JLS 12.6. Finalization of Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6):

> The Java programming language does not specify how soon a finalizer will be invoked, except to say that it will happen before the storage for the object is reused.

You are trying to prove that JVM does not follow the JLS, which would be a bug.

Looking at Azul Zulu OpenJDK 11 source we can observe that finaliztions are run with `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` object which in turn uses `jdk.internal.misc.JavaLangAccess.invokeFinalize(Object)` method to call `Object.finalize()`.

`JavaLangAccess` instance is obtained from `jdk.internal.misc.SharedSecrets` which allows to setup a custom instance of `JavaLangAccess`. Perhaps you could create your own `JavaLangAccess` instance with additional logging in `invokeFinalize()` method?